# GAUTAM -Buddha(BUDDHADEV) and The capability of having several lives for an ordinary man or hallucination?

Tags: personal-experience

A friend of mine said GAUTAM-Buddha(BUDDHADEV) passed through several lives(Births and Rebirths)and finally he attained NIRVANA.In present day context do the experience s feel like walking on an Astro-turf or living in mothers womb.This is my personal experience which should not be considered BLASPHEMY.I divulged my experience to my friend.So he advised me to search books.After death is such an experience possible?

Comment: In this question, I think that you are 1) Saying that you've had the experience, and/or that you remember the experience, of "walking on an space travel or living in mother's womb". Are you then 2) Asking whether that was a hallucination, and/or asking whether such an experience is possible after death, and/or asking whether that's what's meant when it's said that the Buddha passed through several lives?

Comment: I am sorry that my misinterpretation may be dueTO  BUDDHIST LITERATURES VERY OFTEN RAISE THE QUESTION OF REBIRTH AND BUDDHIST TEACHERS TEACH HOW ONE ONE CAN BE FREE FROM REBIRTH.ANOTHER QUESTION IS ABOUT AFTER DEATH EXPERIENCE,WHICH I EXPERIENCED FOR MANY YEARS.BUT I ASK IS IT EASY FOR ONE TO BE FREE FROM REBIRTH.LORD BUDDHA ADDED MANY VALUABLE ADVICES HOW AND WHEN ONE MAN BE FREE.

Comment: I have understood that my experiences  about space etc are illusion and deceptive.I apologize for that part of the question.USER-26375

Answer (score 2):

the path to Nirvana is very simple logic. Here's what I learned from my teacher:

You should divide everything you do (including every word and even every thought) in two groups: whether you're doing it to feed your ego or whether it's actually useful. You have to be very precise. Very precise, with every single word and every single thought you should know why you're doing this. If it's for defending the ego or indulging in pleasure, you should not do it like that, should not think like that or say that. If you're doing it because you think it's actually useful, then you should do it.

> Bhikkhus, before my enlightenment, while I was still only an unenlightened Bodhisatta, it occurred to me: ‘Suppose that I divide my thoughts into two classes. Then I set on one side thoughts of sensual desire, thoughts of ill will, and thoughts of cruelty, and I set on the other side thoughts of renunciation, thoughts of non-ill will, and thoughts of non-cruelty. <sub>MN 19</sub>

Then, when you live like this for several years, your mind will be pure and you will be able to see the path to Nirvana by yourself.

> To avoid all evil, to cultivate good, and to cleanse one's mind — this is the teaching of the Buddhas. <sub>The Dhammapada 14.183</sub>

My teacher said, this world is a magical place where everything is possible, as long as you're free in your mind - and now I know he was right.

So, divide your thoughts like that, and learn to be very very precise with that - and you will see for yourself. This is better than me telling you "Yes, All of that is real". Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable contribution.But how many years it will take to cross the paths to nirvana Lord BUDDHADEV took eighty years.USER26375

Comment: It doesn't matter how long it takes to finish, because every day you do it, it turns your life to better direction, and improves your overall luck and conditions, in my experience. So even if you don't finish, it's still useful - this practice of not allowing crap in your thoughts.

Comment: I marked this answer down. While I agree with most of what is written in it, this answer is opinion based because it does not include any references to Buddhist scriptures. Also, this answer refers to a teacher but does not give credit to who that teacher is. This answer is unsubstantiated.

Comment: Fair point. Is this better?

Comment: @Andrei Volkov-It will take me many years  to understand  The Buddhism site in which way it differs from other sites.The answer and comments are of very HIGH LEVEL.Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

> **A friend of mine said GAUTAM-Buddha(BUDDHADEV) passed through several lives(Births and Rebirths)and finally he attained NIRVANA.**

In original Buddhism, the word 'birth' ('jati') refers to each arising of the view of 'self-belief'. But in later Buddhism, the word 'birth' was misconstrued to refer to 'past lives'. Please refer to SN 22.79, which explains the true meaning of recollecting past births. In other words, when the Buddha said he cycled thru myriad "births" (in [Dhp 153](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.11.budd.html)), this was the previous myriad arisings of egoism.

> **In present day context do the experiences feel like walking on an space travel or living in mothers womb.This is my personal experience
>   which should not be considered BLASPHEMY.**

Since your mind continues to have "self-belief", it is not the same experience as the Buddha. When the Buddha, in the present, recollected his "past births", he recollected how his mind's previous "self-beliefs" were ignorant illusions. Again, refer to SN 22.79.

> **I divulged my experience to my friend.So he advised me to search books.After death is such an experience possible?**

In Buddhism, the goal is to eradicate the belief of "I", "me", "mine" and "self". When the Buddha recollected "past births", this is what occurred. The idea of "self" ended. To quote [SN 22.79](https://legacy.suttacentral.net/en/sn22.79):

> *At Savatthi. “Bhikkhus, those ascetics and brahmins who recollect their manifold past abodes all recollect the five aggregates subject
>   to clinging or a certain one among them. What five?*
>
> *“When recollecting thus, bhikkhus: ‘I had such form in the past,’ it is just form that one recollects. When recollecting: ‘I had such a
>   feeling in the past,’ it is just feeling that one recollects. When
>   recollecting: ‘I had such a perception in the past,’ it is just
>   perception that one recollects. When recollecting: ‘I had such
>   volitional formations in the past,’ it is just volitional formations
>   that one recollects. When recollecting: ‘I had such consciousness in
>   the past,’ it is just consciousness that one recollects.*
>
> *Therefore, bhikkhus, any kind of form whatsoever … Any kind of feeling whatsoever … Any kind of perception whatsoever … Any kind of
>   volitional formations whatsoever … Any kind of consciousness
>   whatsoever, whether past, future, or present, internal or external,
>   gross or subtle, inferior or superior, far or near, all consciousness
>   should be seen as it really is with correct wisdom thus: ‘**This is not
>   mine, this I am not, this is not my self**.’*
>
> *“**This is called, bhikkhus, a noble disciple who dismantles and does not build up; who abandons and does not cling; who scatters and does
>   not amass; who extinguishes and does not kindle**.*

Comment: @dhammadhatu-very hard to understand,I will have to go through your comment many times before I can understand.Thank you.User-26375